# Unable to boot from USB harddrive (WD My passport Ultra)

Tags: partitioning, usb

I've followed this procedure http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ and installed `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` onto the external hdd.

However, whenever I restart my computer and choose to boot from the external HDD, nothing happens. All I get is a dark screen with a line blinking on the top left corner.

I know that it is possible to install `Ubuntu` on this external HDD, so what am I missing ? Do I need to specify which partition of the external HDD to boot from ?

EDIT: I used Rufus, and it still didn't work. I've tried settings on both FAT32 and NTFS

[image: image of my files]

Comment: You did not installed it with that procedure, you created a live file system with a persistency partition. Use a USB pen with a live file system and install it properly, like you would do on any hard disk.

Comment: wait, so what should I do instead? How is my current method incorrect?

Comment: I would use a USB stick and rufus (since you are on Windows) to create a live system, then follow the [installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and select the right hard drive where to install to. PLEASE NOTE: be sure to have a backup of **all** the data that you do not want to lose.

Comment: tried it, instead of displaying that blinking line, it asked me reboot and load a suitable boot device

Answer (score 0):

1) Disconnect your internal HDD.

2) Connect your external HDD

3) Boot from the Ubuntu install media.

4) Install Ubuntu normally.

5) Remove install media and reboot.

6) Connect your internal HDD

Comment: why bother with disconnecting my internal HDD though?

Comment: @user2273795 - So that it will install the bootloader to the external one wihtout you having to mess with manual partitioning.